# What happens to empty ng-content fields

Tags: html, angular, rendering, slots, ng-content

Simple question:

The Angular docs suggest not using ng-content in the case of conditional rendering on the *component* end:

> If your component needs to conditionally render content, or render content multiple times, you should configure that component to accept an  element that contains the content you want to conditionally render.

> Using an  element in these cases is not recommended, because when the consumer of a component supplies the content, that content is always initialized, even if the component does not define an  element or if that  element is inside of an ngIf statement.
> From: https://angular.io/guide/content-projection#conditional-content-projection

Does this apply to the consumers of component slots as well? For example:

```
<custom-table-component>
  <div ng-content-select-directive *ngIf="condition">
      This is a conditionally rendered element inhabiting an ng-content slot of a parent 
      component
  </div>
</custom-table-component>
```

Would the underlying ng-content-select still be rendered if the condition is falsy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to recreate the situation you describe in [this stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-3rayd3?file=src/app/custom-table-component/ng-content-select.directive.ts)

From this it seems that the inner `ng-content` won't render in these cases if the condition is `false`.

```
<div>
  <h1>Inner stuff here:</h1>
  <div style="border: 1px solid red">
    <app-custom-table-component>
      <div ng-content-select-directive *ngIf="false">
        This is a conditionally rendered element inhabiting an ng-content slot of a parent 
        component
    </div>
    </app-custom-table-component>
  </div>

</div>
```

And you can see that there is nothing in the DOM, but the debug info:

[image]

You can try to change the `ngIf` to `true` to see how it appears in the DOM (and the custom directive gets initialized as well, which won't if the `ngIf` is false)

Comment: First off, thanks for spinning everything up and doing a manual check! I altered your example slightly to show where my confusion lies (my fault -- I didn't explain it well enough). See here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ctbtrz?file=src/app/app.component.ts . In devtools, both ultimately show no DOM node creation, so I'm curious whether hiding selectors inside and outside of components are both a bad idea.